# Angular 4 How to update parent component after delete an item in child component

Tags: angular, parent

I have a list of items in parent component (master) and when user clicks one of the items, in another component (child / details) on same page it shows details of the selected item. I have a delete button in child component which deletes the selected item from database.

My question is how can I update list of items in parent component after deleting an item in child component?

Parent Component:

```
export class ProjectListComponent implements OnInit {

  projects : Project[];
  selectedProject: Project;

  constructor(private _projectService: ProjectService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.projects = [];
    this.fetchListOfProjects();
  }

  fetchListOfProjects(){
  this._projectService.getProject()
      .subscribe(projects => {
          this.projects = projects;
       })
   }

   onSelect(project: Project): void {
   this.selectedProject = project;
   }
}
```

Child Component:

```
export class ProjectItemComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() project: Project;
 constructor(private _projectService:ProjectService) { }

 ngOnInit() { }

 onDelete(id:any){
   if(confirm("Are you sure to delete the project?")) {
     this._projectService.deleteProject(id)
       .subscribe(result =>{        
        if(result.status == 204){
          console.log('removed');
        };
      }); 
   }       
 }
}
```

Comment: What Angular version are you using? Please add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: sorry my version is angular 4 and I added all details I have in my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
export class ProjectItemComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() project: Project;
 constructor(private _projectService:ProjectService) { }

 @Output()
 someEvent = new EventEmitter();

 ngOnInit() { }

 onDelete(id:any){
   if(confirm("Are you sure to delete the project?")) {
     this._projectService.deleteProject(id)
       .subscribe(result =>{        
        if(result.status == 204){
          console.log('removed');
          this.someEvent.emit(null);
        };
      }); 
   }       
 }
```

```
<project-item (someEvent)="update()"
```

This way `update()` is called on the parent, when an item is deleted in the child.

Comment: I missed to pass null to the emit function and was spinning my head around.Your answer worked a charm.Thanks a lot.